# Pseudo R2 with pglm package in R. (poisson regression with fixed effect model)

Tags: linear-regression, panel, logistic-regression, fixed, poisson

I need to calculate the Pseudo R2 from some regressions did with `pglm` package, with poisson family and model fixed.

where is the Pseudo R2 in the summary? or how I can calculate it?

```
pglm(y~x+x1, data=pdata, model= within, family=poisson)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Some inquiries for your posted question:

Please provide a  
[minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example),
i.e., the code to reproduce the problem you describe. Furthermore, you  
could add on what you already try to solve the error. Also, please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual  
question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: is a simple question. I dont know what to do that´s why I didn´t put the code

Answer (score 1):

For pseudo R2 calculation, you need the log likelihood or deviance of the null model. In your panel glm with model = "within" above, it is not possible to fit a null model. So you cannot calculate pseudo R2.

If you use `model = "random"` or `model = "pooling"` it will be possible:

```
library(pglm)
dat = data.frame(y = rpois(50,10),x = runif(50),
x1 = rnorm(50),grp = factor(sample(1:2,nrow(dat),replace=TRUE)))
fit =  pglm(y ~ x+x1,data=dat,model="pooling",family="poisson",index="grp")

fit0 =  pglm(y ~ 1,data=dat,model="pooling",family="poisson",index="grp")
```

So using the simplest McFadden rsquared:

[image]

We do:

```
pseudoR2 = as.numeric(1 - logLik(fit)/logLik(fit0))
```